# External Address Problems

Tags: windows-7, networking, port

I would like to create a Minecraft Server, but searching the internet I found that the command ***netstat -an*** allows me to see all active connections and their respective IP's. What happens in my case is that the connection is created but an External Address is not defined, that's what I understood by reading the results of the command.

Below is the address and port line:

[image]

Basically I would like to know if there is anything I can do to make it possible for my friends to connect to my Minecraft Server using my External IP.

Comment: You would have to forward the port to the server. Do you have Administrator access to any and all networking equipment connected to your intranet?

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting your `netstat` results just a bit. Those connections are open, and listening. That means that there is no active connection but that your server is waiting for some other computer to start the connection. That's why you see `0.0.0.0` listed as the foreign address. That's normal. The other address you see is actually the local (private) IP address of your PC. More on that in a second.

If you're looking for how to allow your friends to connect to your Minecraft server, it is possible if you forward the necessary port(s) in your router's configuration options. There are numerous tutorials online about how and why you have to do this, but here's the short, summarized version:

Your Internet Service Provider (ISP) assigns your home with one external/public IP address that all devices in the home share. In order to allow for multiple devices sharing one connection, a router is required. This router uses a technology called Network Address Translation (NAT) to assign a separate local/private IP address to each device connected to it, and then allows that device to share the internet connection. That's the `192.168.0.104` number that you see. That IP address is only usable within your home, and is meaningless outside your home (you can't use it to connect to your Minecraft server unless you're connected to the same home network).

You need to configure your router to forward all traffic on port 25565 to your server, so that when someone does try to connect to your external IP address, that traffic gets forwarded to the correct computer (in this case, the computer running your Minecraft server). What I would do is find your router's model number and search something like "(router model) port forwarding" on Google. Then, you can Google "what's my ip" to get your external (public) IP address which you can give to your friends so they can connect to your server.